# Вызов переменной из функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Хочу добавить кнопку в окно `Toplevel`, но для этого надо занести её в переменную, для того что бы указать место, где она будет находиться.

Но когда я это делаю при выполнении скрипта, интерпретатор говорит, что переменная `top` не определена. Как мне использовать эту переменную?

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

main_frame = Frame(main, width="300", height="300").pack()


def toplevelwin():
    top = Toplevel(main_frame, relief=SUNKEN, width="300", height="300", takefocus=True)


def close_app():
    main.destroy()

Button(top, text="Сохранить", relief=SUNKEN).pack()
Button(main_frame, text="Добавить пароль", command=toplevelwin, relief=FLAT).pack()
Button(main_frame, width="30", text="Закрыть", command=close_app).pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окно `Toplevel()` не существует до вызова `toplevelwin()` функции. Нет нужды создавать кнопку, пока её родитель ещё не создан:

```
def toplevelwin():
    top = Toplevel(main_frame, ...)
    Button(top, text="Сохранить", relief=SUNKEN).pack()
    main.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % top.winfo_pathname(top.winfo_id()))
```